# Getting tags to have nifty icons on them

Tags: feature-request, tags, advertising, sponsored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s this about labelled tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23959/whats-this-about-labelled-tags)

I note that lots of icons have a nifty icon on them (Adobe, Android etc) how do you go about requesting one to be added to a tag?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23959/whats-this-about-labelled-tags

Comment: How is that a dupe? That's about the guy complaining about Flex, not how to get your tag sponsered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Throw a sufficient amount of money at the SO team.  They're sponsored tags.

Comment: +1 ah the old throw-money solution. Works for everything including wives and ex(es).

Comment: To your wives and mistresses, may they never meet.

Answer (score 2):

Hi,

you should contact the Advertising department of StackOverflow, handled by Inedo Media.

The contact form is at http://inedomedia.com/stackoverflow.aspx and you should mention you are interested in sponsoring a tag. This includes the icon, but also a list of sponsored link (See the [Android Tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) for an example)

Be prepared to spend some money though, advertising isn't free.

Comment: "advertising isn't free", heh

Comment: also not free: freedom. http://is.gd/5THlG

Answer (score 1):

Check the [advertising info](http://inedomedia.com/stackoverflow.aspx) linked to in the footer of the page.