# What happens when a tag means two things?

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle tags with multiple meanings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6928/how-to-handle-tags-with-multiple-meanings)

I was looking at the [mex tag on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mex), and I noticed that two completely different topics were being tagged as "mex". Roughly two-thirds were using MEX to discuss MATLAB MEX-files, which are C/C++ and Fortran extensions for the MATLAB language, and the other third had something to do with Web Services Metadata Exchange (something I'm far less familiar with). Is there a protocol for handling this? Does it matter?

Comment: good question but isn't this a dupe? Can't seem to find it though!

Comment: Nothing until it gets to be a problem. See for instance http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23959/2509.

Comment: It felt like it might be a dup, but I couldn't find anything either. dmckee's link is for a similar problem, but there's no "what's the general rule" question.

Comment: The reason I asked this is that I just got done adding a tag wiki (well, someone else approved it, I don't have that much rep), and my wiki doesn't mention Metadata Exchange because I didn't realize there was this other vein of questions until I looked more closely. Now I'm wondering if I made a mistake doing so.