# rename [gnu-flex] to [flex-lexer]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

1. Flex is [not](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Is-flex-GNU-or-not_003f.html#Is-flex-GNU-or-not_003f) part of the GNU project.
2. `flex-lexer` is much more discoverable than `gnu-flex`. When I search for the tag I will start typing `f`, not `g`.
3. It is the way [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser) does it.

Comment: +1 just to fix the misnomer

Comment: The worst part of it is that this [was brought up when the mis-tag was first made](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23959/whats-this-about-labelled-tags/23962#23962), lo these many years ago.

Comment: I just found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281870/dependency-problems-with-flex-bison) with the [tag:gnu-flex] tag and the amount of wrongness with the tag was astonishing. I'm stunned that it has persisted for this long... I'd also be happy with letting the 25-year-old program have the [tag:flex] tag outright, and let Adobe Flex have [tag:adobe-flex] or [flex-flashy] or something similar... (Yes, that's just me being bitter.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several people (one of them me, at least one other person too — thanks for the assist, whoever you were; I think one other person was [lesmana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360899/lesmana)) have eliminated the [gnu-flex](/questions/tagged/gnu-flex) tag from questions, replacing it with [flex-lexer](/questions/tagged/flex-lexer).  In due course, the [gnu-flex](/questions/tagged/gnu-flex) will vanish as there is no use of it any more.

Comment: The other person was me. I thank you too.